# Bluetooth mouse paring in Linux Mint Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, mouse, cinnamon, bluetooth

I'm having an hard time trying to pair my Apple magic mouse on Mint Cinnamon... keyboard pairing was fast and dead simple, but due to a weird behavior in the gui I'm not able to enter the code for pairing my mouse!!
Basically once the mouse is discoverede by the OS, it shows a notification with an input field for enter the code, BUT as soon I start typing into it the notification is dismissed... WTF?! How can I pair my mouse if I can't type the code? (I installed bluez-tools in order to try the pairing from the command line, but the problem is the same, 'cause in the end it still invokes the OS notification for the user input :()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved by following this: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=125166 (I was a step away from the success :P)